# Show that the group cannot be of composite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If  $G\neq \{e\}$ has no proper non-trivial subgroups, show that the group cannot be of composite order.

If $G$ is non-trivial then there exist at least one element $a$ such that $a\neq e$. If I assume that there exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $H\neq \{e\}$ then that case become impossible.
I am unable to solve the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you know there is $a\neq e$, so consider the subgroup generated by it. It can't be a proper subgroup, so $a$ has composite order. Now consider some power of $a$...

Expanded hint: Suppose $a$ has order $bc$ with $b,c>1$. What can you say about $\langle a^b\rangle$?

Comment: Given $G\neq \{e\}$. Consider $H=<a>$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of G. How you get "so a has composite order"

Comment: I've assumed for contradiction that $G$ has composite order (though I forgot to mention that in the hint). Since $G$ has no nontrivial subgroups, $\langle a\rangle=H=G$, hence order of $a$, which is also the size of $\langle a\rangle$, is equal to $o(G)$.

Comment: I understand upto this. Please write the next step "Now consider some power of a" in details.

Comment: @rama_ran As you wish.

Comment: Let $n=o(a)=o(G)=bc$. Then $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}=a^n=e$ then $o(a^b)<n$. But how to show that n is prime?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $o(G)<\infty $ is composite .Let $o(G)=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ where $p_i's$ are primes.

By *Cauchy's Theorem* $G$ has an element of order $p_1$ say $a$. Then $\langle a\rangle $ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ where $e\neq \langle a\rangle \subsetneq  G$

**ALTER**:Since $n=o(G)$ is composite so $n$ has at least two distinct prime factors say $p,q$.

Since $G\neq \{e\}$ so there exists $a(\neq e)\in G$ .Now consider $ \langle a\rangle  $.

**CASE I**:If $G=\langle a\rangle $. Then $o(a)=n$.

Now consider the cyclic group generated by $a^p$. Then $\langle a^p\rangle \subsetneq \langle a\rangle=G$.

So $G$ has subgroup $\langle a^p\rangle $ which is false.

**CASE II**: $G\neq \langle a\rangle $. Then $\langle a\rangle $ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ which 
is false again

Comment: You can't assume $o(G)=pq$, the order might have more complicated factorization.

Comment: As you appear to have noticed, Cauchy's Theorem is completely unnecessary to use here. In fact, your new altered (elementary) proof seems to be identical to Wojowu's...

Comment: @learnmore How do you understand that $o(G)=$finite ?

Comment: Interesting !@rama_ran;Have  you ever heard of an infinite composite number?Please give an example ..Question says **cannot be of composite order**

Comment: @learnmore No no, I don't want to say the existance of neaning of "infinite composite number". I want to mention that if G is a group then its order may be finite or may be infinite. If it is finite, then we check whether it is of prime order or composite order. If it is not finite then there is no question of prime/composite. So here, it is necessary to prove that under the given condition, G if of finite order. I want to know how to prove that?

Comment: I did not prove that $o(G)$ is finite ;you have given it in the problem itself@rama_ran

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is composite its order has either two prime factors in which case the Sylow theorems guarantees us proper subgroups, eiter it has order $p^k$ with prime $p$ and integer $k >1$ in which case the Cauchy theorem assures us a proper subgroup of order $p$.